# Turn off notification sounds and vibrations while allowing phone calls to trigger sound and/or vibration on Nexus 5

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, audio, vibration

I have a Nexus 5 running Android 4.3.2. I want to turn off all sound and vibration notifications for all apps, while allowing phone calls to trigger sound and/or vibrations. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried following the advice at [How can I turn off Notification Sounds and leave phone sounds on](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16149/how-can-i-turn-off-notification-sounds-and-leave-phone-sounds-on) but the answers don't work. There's no separate slider for notifications, and the AudioManager app doesn't shut off vibrations. I have tried the [official Google answer](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2908717?hl=en#) but there's no setting, **Vibrate -> Never**, and setting notifications to silent does not stop the vibrations. I've tried the individual app settings, too, but there's no setting for vibration in the official twitter app, for example.

I can stop specific apps from sending any notifications at all, but that's not what I want. I want the notifications to show up in the drop-down, I just don't want any sounds or vibrations.

Comment: https://twitter.com/ScarySloth/status/413127987681169408 states that you can turn it off in twitter from the account settings rather than the general settings. Perhaps the answer is that this IS ALWAYS configurable on a per-app basis?

Comment: Just to back up your findings on twitter, I've always thought it was a per-app setting and acted on that. Turning the phone to vibrate/silent mode will override individual app settings though - to my understanding.

Comment: @dotVezz that's exactly it. If you want all apps bar one to do something you  have to change all the apps individually. The vibrate/silent mode will override this setting, but that is obviously for ALL apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue I have as well, it lies with the apps, whose settings override the default ringer and vibration settings. In order to completely disable vibrations you will have to disable them in Settings > Sound, and individually in each app.

Twitter app you will have to go to Settings >  and there is a Notification Settings sections that allows you to disable vibration.

As an aspiring developer, it will be my goal to default to system settings but allow for customization, as it should be...

Comment: Thank you, and particularly thank you for your plans to default your app to the existing system settings.

Answer (score -1):

Go to **settings**> **Sounds**> then there should be an option **Vibrate** there should be **vibrator intensity** and click on it and you can take off the vibrating off your phone for completely even on apps that were still vibrating even though phone would be on silent.

Comment: It's not there on Nexus 5 running stock AOSP, which is the device used by OP. Which phone model, Android version, and custom ROM are you testing this on?

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Settings -> Notificaton Manager` and change the settings.

Comment: I do not have an option called `Notification Manager` under settings. Could you edit your answer and expand it to say how that will allow the original asker to turn off all notification sounds?

Comment: Also, just in case, please mention the device model, Android version, and whether you're using custom ROM or not. These 3 factors usually affect the setting.

Answer (score -3):

`Settings -> Device -> Audio profiles -> General -> Options (next to General) -> Default notification sound -> Silent` (it is the first option from the top)

Comment: There is no such setting on my Nexus 5.

Comment: Just in case, please mention the device model, Android version, and whether you're using custom ROM or not. These 3 factors usually affect the setting.

Answer (score -4):

`Setting -> Audio Profile -> Create a new profile` will allow to you to set it up.

Comment: There is no such setting.

Comment: Just in case, please mention the device model, Android version, and whether you're using custom ROM or not. These 3 factors usually affect the setting.