# Weird volume behaviour in Android 6.0.1

Tags: audio

My wife's Nexus 5 recently started behaving very weirdly.

For notifications, it always think that it's in silent mode (i.e. it vibrates and doesn't play a sound). This happens regardless of the actual volume settings. All other sounds seem to work properly (ringtones, in-call volume, etc.)

Also, when she presses volume up or down, it adjusts the in-call volume instead ringtone volume.

I have tried rebooting, and I even tried deleting the cache (as described here - https://android.stackexchange.com/a/139739/165076) but nothing seems to help.

Comment: I wonder if this is sort of the inverse of [this question over here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59203/turn-off-notification-sounds-and-vibrations-while-allowing-phone-calls-to-trigge). Perhaps something in the settings got disabled specifically for notifications - have you checked the sound settings?

Comment: Notification sound is linked to Ringer volume in stock Android 6.0.1. See if your wife installed an Xposed module.

Comment: @Firelord she doesn't have any Xposed modules installed

Comment: @dotVezz - I am pretty sure that I checked all of those settings, I'll double check the next time I have a chance